# how to use Minio-go sdk to download files in chunks concurrently？

Tags: go, minio

I want to know how to use Minio to download files in chunks concurrently, and then finally merge the chunks and return them to the client. Here's the code I wrote. I thought opts.PartNumber = partNumber would do the chunk download, but I got an error: %!! (MISSING)(EXTRA minio.ErrorRe=416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable)

```
package logic
import (
    "Gopan/common/errorx"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/minio/minio-go/v7"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "github.com/zeromicro/go-zero/core/logc"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"

    "Gopan/app/download/api/internal/svc"
    "Gopan/app/download/api/internal/types"

    "github.com/zeromicro/go-zero/core/logx"
)

const (
    bucket    = "userfile"
    outputDir = "/Users/liuxian/GoProjects/project/Gopan/data/file/download/"
    chunkSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 // The size of each block（1MB）
)
type DownloadMinioLogic struct {
    logx.Logger
    ctx    context.Context
    svcCtx *svc.ServiceContext
}
func NewDownloadMinioLogic(ctx context.Context, svcCtx *svc.ServiceContext) *DownloadMinioLogic {
    return &DownloadMinioLogic{
        Logger: logx.WithContext(ctx),
        ctx:    ctx,
        svcCtx: svcCtx,
    }
}

func (l *DownloadMinioLogic) downloadFilePart(client *minio.Client, bucket, object string, partNumber int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan<- string) {
    defer wg.Done()

    // 创建文件以保存下载的分块
    // Creates a file to save the downloaded blocks
    filePath := outputDir + fmt.Sprintf("part%d", partNumber)

    // 设置分块下载的选项
    // Set the option to block download
    opts := minio.GetObjectOptions{}
    opts.PartNumber = partNumber
    // 下载分块并将其写入文件
    // Download the block and write it to the file
    err := client.FGetObject(context.Background(), bucket, object, filePath, opts)
    if err != nil {
        logc.Errorf(l.ctx, "下载分块失败:", err)
        // Sending an empty string to the channel indicates that the download failed
        ch <- "" // 将空字符串发送到通道表示下载失败
        return
    }
    // // If the file path is sent to the channel, the download is successful
    ch <- filePath // 将文件路径发送到通道表示下载成功
}

func (l *DownloadMinioLogic) mergeFileParts(outputDir, outputFileName string, totalParts int) error {
    // 创建输出文件以保存合并后的文件
    // Create an output file to save the merged file
    outputPath := filepath.Join(outputDir, outputFileName)
    outputFile, err := os.Create(outputPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer outputFile.Close()

    // 将每个分块的内容合并到输出文件中
    // Merge the contents of each block into the output file
    for i := 1; i <= totalParts; i++ {
        partPath := outputDir + fmt.Sprintf("part%d", i)
        partData, err := os.ReadFile(partPath)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        _, err = outputFile.Write(partData)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // 删除已合并的分块文件
        // Delete the merged block file
        if err := os.Remove(partPath); err != nil {
            logc.Errorf(l.ctx, "无法删除分块文件:", err)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func (l *DownloadMinioLogic) downloadAndMergeFile(client *minio.Client, bucket, object, outputDir, outputFileName string, totalParts int) error {
    // 创建通道以接收成功下载的分块文件路径
    // Create a channel to receive the path of the successfully downloaded block file
    ch := make(chan string, totalParts)

    // 并发下载分块
        // Concurrent download blocks
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for partNumber := 0; partNumber < totalParts; partNumber++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go l.downloadFilePart(client, bucket, object, partNumber, &wg, ch)
    }

    // 等待所有分块下载完成
    // Wait for all block downloads to complete
    wg.Wait()

    // 检查分块下载是否成功
    // Check whether the block download is successful
    close(ch)
    for filePath := range ch {
        if filePath == "" {
            return fmt.Errorf("下载分块失败")
        }
    }

    // 合并分块为完整文件
    // Merge into chunks into complete files
    err := l.mergeFileParts(outputDir, outputFileName, totalParts)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
func (l *DownloadMinioLogic) DownloadMinio(req *types.DownloadMinioReq, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    // todo: add your logic here and delete this line
    // 获取对象信息
    // Obtain object information
    fmt.Println(req)
    object := req.FileAddr
    outputFileName := req.FileName
    info, err := l.svcCtx.MinioDb.StatObject(l.ctx, bucket, object, minio.StatObjectOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(errorx.NewDefaultError("无法获取对象信息"), "无法获取对象信息 err:%v", err)

    }

    // 计算分块的数量
    // Calculate the number of blocks
    totalParts := int((info.Size + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize)
    fmt.Println(totalParts)
    // 下载并合并文件
    // Download and merge files
    err = l.downloadAndMergeFile(l.svcCtx.MinioDb, bucket, object, outputDir, outputFileName, totalParts)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(errorx.NewDefaultError("下载文件失败"), "下载文件失败 err:%v", err)

    }

    // 打开合并后的文件
    // Open the merged file
    filePath := filepath.Join(outputDir, outputFileName)
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(errorx.NewDefaultError("无法打开文件"), "无法打开文件 err:%v", err)

    }
    defer file.Close()
    // 校验文件sha1
    //if req.FileSha1 != utils.FileSha1(file) {
    //  return errors.Wrapf(errorx.NewCodeError(40004, errorx.ErrFileSha1Falsify), "err:文件sha1值校验失败文件已经被篡改:file:%v", req)
    //}
    // 设置响应头
    // Set the response header
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=%s", outputFileName))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))

    // 将文件内容发送给客户端
    // Send the file contents to the client
    _, err = io.Copy(w, file)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(errorx.NewDefaultError("无法发送文件内容"), "无法发送文件内容 err:%v", err)
    }

    // 删除已发送的合并文件
    // Delete the sent merge file
    if err := os.Remove(filePath); err != nil {
        logc.Error(l.ctx, "无法删除合并文件:", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

err:

```json
{"level":"error","ts":1690259678.581509,"caller":"logc/logs.go:57","msg":"下载分块失败:%!!(MISSING)(EXTRA minio.ErrorRe=416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable)","caller":"logic/downloadminiologic.go:54","trace":"8973d826b968f8c9668e50c51cf3d11d","span":"57a9fe121cf6ef2f","stacktrace":"github.com/zeromicro/go-zero/core/logc.Errorf\n\t/Users/liuxian/GoProjects/pkg/mod/github.com/zeromicro/go-zero@v1.5.3/core/logc/logs.go:57\nGopan/app/download/api/internal/logic.(*DownloadMinioLogic).downloadFilePart\n\t/Users/liuxian/GoProjects/project/Gopan/app/download/api/internal/logic/downloadminiologic.go:54"}
```